# Unexpected output in Python

Tags: python, list

After appending the elements from list `a` into list `b`, when list `a` is cleared it automatically clears the elements of list `a` in list `b`. I don't understand how the list `b[0]` is empty. Can you help me with the error in this code.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]

b = list()

b.append(a)

a.clear()

print(a)

print(b)
```

Actual output:

```
[]

[[]]
```

Expected output:

```
[]
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Use `b.append(a.copy())` to generate a new object

Comment: When you append `a` into your list you are essentially adding a reference to that list object. Meaning any changes you make to `a` will be reflected on what you see in `b[0]`. To prevent this you can create a copy of your list and append this instead like @mozway suggested. The copy is a new object which is then independend of `a`.